# sed doesn't replace variable

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to replace some regex line in a apache file.
i define:

```
OLD1="[0-9]*.[0-9]+"

NEW1="[a-z]*.[0-9]"
```

when i'm executing:

```
sed -i 's/$OLD1/$NEW1/g' demo.conf
```

there's no change.

This is what i tried to do

```
sed -i "s/${OLD1}/${NEW1}/g" 001-kms.conf

sed -i "s/"$OLD1"/"$NEW1"/g" 001-kms.conf

sed -i "s~${OLD1}~${NEW1}~g" 001-kms.conf
```

i'm expecting that the new file will replace $OLD1 with $NEW1

Comment: are you seeing any errors?

Comment: What are the contents of your file?

Comment: You must use `-E` for extended regex option to use `+` in sed. So `sed -E -i 's/$OLD1/$NEW1/g' demo.conf `

Comment: Please try to make it work without variables first

Comment: `in a apache file` - it will be easier to do such as `sed "s/some_option=.*/some_option="new_regex"/`. `some regex line` - what is the regex line exactly in apache file?

Answer (score 3):

### you need matching on exact string

You would need something that can match on exact string `[0-9]*.[0-9]+` which `sed` does not support well.

Therefore instead I am using this pipeline replacing one character at a time 
(it also is easier to read I think):
`echo "[0-9]*.[0-9]+" | sed 's/0/a/' | sed 's/9/z/' | sed 's/+//'`

You would have to `cat` your files or use `find` with execute to then apply this pipe.

**I had tried following (from other SO answers)**:
 
 - `sed 's/\<exact_string/>/replacement/'`
doesn't work as `\<` and `\>` are **left** and **right** **word boundaries** respectively.
 
 - `sed 's/(CB)?exact_string/replacement/'`
found in one answer but nowhere in documentation

I used **Win 10 bash**, **git bash**, and [online Linux tools](https://tio.run) with the same results.

### when I thought matching was on the pattern rather than exact string

**Replacement cannot be a regex** - at most it can reference parts of the regex expression which matched. From [`man sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> `s/regexp/replacement/`
>   Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space. If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement. The replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the regexp.

Additionally you have to escape some characters in your regex (specifically `.` and `+`) unless you add option `-E` for extended regex as per comment under your question.
 <sub>(N.B. only if you want to match on the full-stop `.` rather than it meaning `any character`)</sub>

```
$ echo "01.234--ZZZ" | sed 's/[0-9]*\.[0-9]\+/REPLACEMENT/g'
REPLACEMENT--ZZZ
```

Answer (score 3):

```
OLD1="[0-9]*.[0-9]+"
```

Because the `[` `*` `.` are all characters with special meaning in sed, we need to escape them. For such simple case something like this could work:

```
OLD2=$(<<<"$OLD1" sed 's/[][\*\.]/\\&/g')
```

It will set `OLD2` to `\[0-9\]\*\.\[0-9\]+`. Note that it doesn't handle all the possible cases, like `OLD1='\.\['` will convert to `OLD2='\\.\\[` which means something different. Implementing a proper regex to properly escape, well, other regex I leave as an exercise to others.

Now you can:

```
sed "s/$OLD2/$NEW1/g"
```

Tested with:

```
OLD1="[0-9]*.[0-9]+"
NEW1="[a-z]*.[0-9]"
sed "s/$(sed 's/[][\*\.]/\\&/g' <<<"$OLD1")/$NEW1/g" <<<'XYZ="[0-9]*.[0-9]+"'
```

will output:

```
XYZ="[a-z]*.[0-9]"
```

Comment: thanks, this does replace as needed however with these variable it doesn't work:
```
OLD1="<DirectoryMatch "/opt/om/apps/fe/base/[0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]*/*">"
NEW1"<DirectoryMatch "/opt/om/apps/fe/base/[a-z]+/*">" 
```
any idea?

Comment: I guess escape the `/` too.  [Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) is a good introduction to basic posix regex. [Here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is the amazing sed introduction. Why not just `s@<DirectoryMatch "/opt/om/apps/fe/base/.*@something else@` ?